# how do i add an active class on the parent li when i select an item on it. using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
            .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $("#nav ul li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

here is the js that I am using to put active class on the li.
it works fine, but when I am selecting an item (the child) inside my sorta like dropdown list. it will get an active class, but i also want the parent li to get an active class also.

```
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
<div id="nav">

    <ul>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="index.jsp"><b>HOME</b></a></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="link.jsp"><b>HOW TO
                    DONATE</b></a></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a class="tangina" href="#"><b>DONATE</b></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="link2.jsp"><b>DONATION
                            CENTER <img id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" />
                    </b></a></li>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="link3.jsp"><b>HOW ELSE
                            CAN I DONATE? <img id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" />
                    </b></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="#"><b>GET DONORS</b></a></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="#"><b>ABOUT BLOOD</b></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="Bfacts.jsp"><b>BLOOD
                            FACTS <img id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" />
                    </b></a></li>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="news.jsp"><b>NEWS <img
                            id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" /></b></a></li>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="faqs.jsp"><b>FAQS <img
                            id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" /></b></a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li class="headerFont"><a href="about.jsp"><b>ABOUT US</b></a></li>

        <li class="headerFont"><a href="login.jsp"><b>LOG IN</b></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="headerFont"><a href="#"><b>REGISTER <img
                            id="arrow" src="img/arrow.png" /></b></a></li>
            </ul></li>

    </ul>

</div>
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle2"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery `.parent()` option? i.e. `$(this).parent().addClass('active');`

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: `$(this).closest("li").addClass('active').` inside your `$("#nav ul li a").each(function(){ if(...){...  //Here } });`

Comment: yeah but i think Im doing it wrong. since Im a newbie in js. where do I add it?

Comment: I tried "$(this).closest("li").addClass('active')." yet the parent li is not getting an active class still.

Comment: Firat of all, please show us which element did you attach a click event listener to.

Comment: it's still not making the parent class to active

Answer (score 5):

Change this line

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

to

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

The `closest` operator tells jQuery to look for the nearest `li` in the DOM tree.  In this case, the nearest parent.

---

## A better `href` string slicing method:

**[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12h07o8y/2/)

And here's a better (*read: more accurate*) string slicing function:

```
/* start of code...*/
var pgurl = sliceString(window.location.href);
/*... rest of code */

function sliceString(s) {
    s = s.split("").reverse().join("");
    if (s.indexOf('/') === 0){
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('/'));
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

This will remove any trailing `/` character, and more accurately select the end-of-string url you're looking for.

---

## Edit, the second:

Alright, if you want ***all*** parents to be selected then you can use the `parents()` selector like so:

```
$(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
```

**[Another fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/12h07o8y/3/)**

---

## Final edit:

The third solution I provided does select the `li` that has the `a` element which was clicked, as well as all its parent `li` elements.  Keep in mind that the top-level `li` (`headerFont` in your provided example) contains all the child `li` items as well, not just the one that was clicked.  If you only want the text selected for `DONATE`, then add that to your CSS like

```
nav > ul > li.active b,
nav > ul > li > ul li.active {
  /* ACTIVE STYLES */
}
```

Those two CSS selectors combined will select the top-level `b` element in your nav, as well as an non-top-level `li` element that was clicked.

Comment: Just tried it but parent still not getting active class

Comment: Are you sure?  I'd check how you're selecting that substring, then.  [Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/12h07o8y/)

Comment: The problem is likely how you're pulling the substring.  I'll edit in my answer a better way to do that.

Comment: oohh what I meant by parent was the list holding the list(the dropdown items). for example, when i select news(which is inside about blood) I want both of them to have an active class.

Comment: but how do I only set the parent and the selected child only to have an active class? for example I selected blood facts. so the blood facts will get an active class + it's parent which is about blood.

Comment: @PeterYambao What about the `parents` method doesn't do that for you?  Can you edit your answer highlighting the elements that you want to have the active class?

Comment: Check my latest answer @Josh Burgess (sorry for asking a lot of questions still a newbie at javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```